# Error finding attribute `feature_names_in_` that exists in docs

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, scikit-learn-pipeline

I'm getting the error `AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'feature_names_in_'` even though that attribute is written [in the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

I'm on `scikit-learn` version `1.0.2`.

I created an object `LogisticRegression` and I am trying to use the documented attribute of `feature_names_in_` but it's returning an error.

```
#imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statistics
import scipy.sparse

from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# train_test_split()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, random_state = 42)


#create functions for preprocessing

# function to replace NaN's in the ordinal and interval data 
def replace_NAN_median(X_df):
    opinions = ['opinion_seas_vacc_effective', 'opinion_seas_risk', 'opinion_seas_sick_from_vacc', 'household_adults',
                'household_children']
    for column in opinions:
        X_df[column].replace(np.nan, X_df[column].median(), inplace = True)
    return X_df

# function to replace NaN's in the catagorical data     
def replace_NAN_mode(X_df):
    miss_cat_features = ['education', 'income_poverty', 'marital_status', 'rent_or_own', 'employment_status']
    for column in miss_cat_features:
        X_df[column].replace(np.nan, statistics.mode(X_df[column]), inplace = True)
    return X_df


# Instantiate transformers
NAN_median = FunctionTransformer(replace_NAN_median)
NAN_mode = FunctionTransformer(replace_NAN_mode)

col_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=
    # replace NaN's in the binary data                                
    [("NAN_0", SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='constant', fill_value = 0), 
    ['behavioral_antiviral_meds', 'behavioral_avoidance','behavioral_face_mask' ,
    'behavioral_wash_hands', 'behavioral_large_gatherings', 'behavioral_outside_home',
    'behavioral_touch_face', 'doctor_recc_seasonal', 'chronic_med_condition', 
    'child_under_6_months', 'health_worker', 'health_insurance']),
    
     # MinMaxScaler on our numeric ordinal and interval data
    ("scaler", MinMaxScaler(), ['opinion_seas_vacc_effective', 'opinion_seas_risk',
                                'opinion_seas_sick_from_vacc', 
                                'household_adults', 'household_children']),
     
     # OHE catagorical string data
    ("ohe", OneHotEncoder(sparse = False), ['age_group','education', 'race', 'sex', 
                                'income_poverty', 'marital_status', 'rent_or_own',
                                'employment_status', 'census_msa'])],
     
    remainder="passthrough")


# Preprocessing Pipeline 
preprocessing_pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("NAN_median", NAN_median), 
    ("NAN_mode", NAN_mode), 
    ("col_transformer", col_transformer)
    ])

# model
logreg_optimized_pipe =  Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessing_pipe", preprocessing_pipe),
                                    ("log_reg", LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear', random_state = 42, C = 10, penalty= 'l1'))])

#fit model to training data
logreg_optimized_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

#trying to get feature names
logreg_optimized_pipe.named_steps["log_reg"].feature_names_in_


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-512bfaf5962d> in <module>
----> 1 logreg_optimized_pipe.named_steps["log_reg"].feature_names_in_
      

AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'feature_names_in_'
```

I'm open to alternative suggestions on how to get the feature names as well.

Comment: You mention that your sklearn version is 1.0.2, but your link is to version 1.2.0. Make sure you are looking at the right docs or update the sklearn version.

Comment: The column transformer has converted the data to a numpy array, so the logistic regression indeed has never seen column names. You can use the column transformer's `get_feature_names[_out]` method(s), but I don't know offhand whether each of the transformers you used had the required method by 1.0.2 yet.

Comment: There's one problem to consider with your `replace_...` functions/transformers: on test data, they'll impute with the median/mode _of that test dataset_, when you should prefer to impute with the median/mode saved from the training set.

Answer (score 1):

Docs says the following:

> feature_names_in_ndarray of shape (n_features_in_,)
> Names of features seen during fit. **Defined only when X has feature names that are all strings.**

You should make sure that data that reaches model has names in.
Also, it is defined only when fit is called.

Link to the docs for your version 1.0.2
[LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/1.0/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html?highlight=logistic#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression)

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that `SimpleImputer` returns an array - thereby removing the column names. I replaced `SimpleImputer` with a function to fix this. I wasn't able to figure out how to use `.feature_names_in_` on the `LogisticRegression()` model, but it did work when I called it on the preprocessing pipeline `ColumnTransformer`, and most importantly I was able to use `.get_feature_names_out()` on the preprocessing pipeline to get the feature names that were fed into the model.

Code:

```python
#imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statistics
import scipy.sparse

from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# train_test_split()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, random_state = 42)


#create functions for preprocessing

# function to replace NaN's in the ordinal and interval data 
def replace_NAN_median(X_df):
    opinions = ['opinion_seas_vacc_effective', 'opinion_seas_risk', 'opinion_seas_sick_from_vacc', 'household_adults',
                'household_children']
    for column in opinions:
        X_df[column].replace(np.nan, X_df[column].median(), inplace = True)
    return X_df

# function to replace NaN's in the catagorical data     
def replace_NAN_mode(X_df):
    miss_cat_features = ['education', 'income_poverty', 'marital_status', 'rent_or_own', 'employment_status']
    for column in miss_cat_features:
        X_df[column].replace(np.nan, statistics.mode(X_df[column]), inplace = True)
    return X_df
# function to replace NaN's in the binary data 
                           
def replace_NAN_0(X_df):
    miss_binary = ['behavioral_antiviral_meds', 'behavioral_avoidance','behavioral_face_mask' ,
    'behavioral_wash_hands', 'behavioral_large_gatherings', 'behavioral_outside_home',
    'behavioral_touch_face', 'doctor_recc_seasonal', 'chronic_med_condition', 
    'child_under_6_months', 'health_worker', 'health_insurance']
    for column in miss_binary:
        X_df[column].replace(np.nan, 0, inplace = True)
    return X_df


# Instantiate transformers
NAN_median = FunctionTransformer(replace_NAN_median)
NAN_mode = FunctionTransformer(replace_NAN_mode)
NAN_0 = FunctionTransformer(replace_NAN_0)
col_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers= [
     # MinMaxScaler on our numeric ordinal and interval data
    ("scaler", MinMaxScaler(), ['opinion_seas_vacc_effective', 'opinion_seas_risk',
                                'opinion_seas_sick_from_vacc', 
                                'household_adults', 'household_children']),
     
     # OHE catagorical string data
    ("ohe", OneHotEncoder(sparse = False), ['age_group','education', 'race', 'sex', 
                                'income_poverty', 'marital_status', 'rent_or_own',
                                'employment_status', 'census_msa'])],
     
    remainder="passthrough")


# Preprocessing Pipeline 
preprocessing_pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("NAN_median", NAN_median), 
    ("NAN_mode", NAN_mode),
    ("NAN_0", NAN_0),
    ("col_transformer", col_transformer)
    ])

# model
logreg_optimized_pipe =  Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessing_pipe", preprocessing_pipe),
                                    ("log_reg", LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear', random_state = 42, C = 10, penalty= 'l1'))])

#fit model to training data
logreg_optimized_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

#trying to get feature names
logreg_optimized_pipe.named_steps["preprocessing_pipe"][3].feature_names_in_

#output - feature names put into `ColumnTransformer`
array(['respondent_id', 'behavioral_antiviral_meds',
   'behavioral_avoidance', 'behavioral_face_mask',
   'behavioral_wash_hands', 'behavioral_large_gatherings',
   'behavioral_outside_home', 'behavioral_touch_face',
   'doctor_recc_seasonal', 'chronic_med_condition',
   'child_under_6_months', 'health_worker', 'health_insurance',
   'opinion_seas_vacc_effective', 'opinion_seas_risk',
   'opinion_seas_sick_from_vacc', 'age_group', 'education', 'race',
   'sex', 'income_poverty', 'marital_status', 'rent_or_own',
   'employment_status', 'census_msa', 'household_adults',
   'household_children'], dtype=object)

logreg_optimized_pipe.named_steps["preprocessing_pipe"][3].get_feature_names_out()

#output - feature names after `ColumnTransformer`
array(['scaler__opinion_seas_vacc_effective', 'scaler__opinion_seas_risk',
   'scaler__opinion_seas_sick_from_vacc', 'scaler__household_adults',
   'scaler__household_children', 'ohe__age_group_18 - 34 Years',
   'ohe__age_group_35 - 44 Years', 'ohe__age_group_45 - 54 Years',
   'ohe__age_group_55 - 64 Years', 'ohe__age_group_65+ Years',
   'ohe__education_12 Years', 'ohe__education_< 12 Years',
   'ohe__education_College Graduate', 'ohe__education_Some College',
   'ohe__race_Black', 'ohe__race_Hispanic',
   'ohe__race_Other or Multiple', 'ohe__race_White',
   'ohe__sex_Female', 'ohe__sex_Male',
   'ohe__income_poverty_<= $75,000, Above Poverty',
   'ohe__income_poverty_> $75,000',
   'ohe__income_poverty_Below Poverty', 'ohe__marital_status_Married',
   'ohe__marital_status_Not Married', 'ohe__rent_or_own_Own',
   'ohe__rent_or_own_Rent', 'ohe__employment_status_Employed',
   'ohe__employment_status_Not in Labor Force',
   'ohe__employment_status_Unemployed',
   'ohe__census_msa_MSA, Not Principle  City',
   'ohe__census_msa_MSA, Principle City', 'ohe__census_msa_Non-MSA',
   'remainder__respondent_id', 'remainder__behavioral_antiviral_meds',
   'remainder__behavioral_avoidance',
   'remainder__behavioral_face_mask',
   'remainder__behavioral_wash_hands',
   'remainder__behavioral_large_gatherings',
   'remainder__behavioral_outside_home',
   'remainder__behavioral_touch_face',
   'remainder__doctor_recc_seasonal',
   'remainder__chronic_med_condition',
   'remainder__child_under_6_months', 'remainder__health_worker',
   'remainder__health_insurance'], dtype=object)
```